# How to split a none digit text inside a String into charterers but keep all the numbers?

Tags: java, regex, split

I have a string mixed with digits and none digits, how to split the none digits (including Space) into character but keep all the number

Input:

```
ab:123+234-345*456///+ hi100
```

Output:

```
["a", "b", ":","123", "+", "234","-", "345", "*","456", "/", "/","/", "+", " ", "h", "i", "100"]
```

I tried this

```
regx = "|(?<=\\s)|(?<=\\D)(?=\\d)|(?<=\\d)(?=\\D)|((?<=\\s+)|(=\\s+))|^\\D";
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use this regex with an alternation for matching:

```
\d+|\D
```

There are 2 alternatives in this regex:

- `\d+`: Match 1+ digits
- `\D`: Match a non-digit

Use this match in a while loop.

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/Y0wcXv/3)

**Code:**

```
final String regex = "\\d+|\\D";
final String string = "ab:123+234-345*456///+hi100";

final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
final Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(string);

List<String> result = new ArrayList<>();

while (matcher.find()) {
      result.add ( matcher.group() );
}

System.out.println( result );
```

---

Alternatively you may use this regex for `split`:

```
(?!^)(?=\D)|(?<=\D)(?=\d)
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/Y0wcXv/2)

**Code:**

```
String[] result = str.split( "(?!^)(?=\\D)|(?<=\\D)(?=\\d)" );
```

Comment: Does `.group(0)` not return the first match?

Comment: `matcher.group(0)` is same as `matcher.group()`. It returns complete match

Answer (score 3):

You can use the regex, `\d+|\D` which means either digits (i.e. `\d+`) or (i.e. `|`) a non-digit (`\D`).

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String str = "ab:123+234-345*456";
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\d+|\\D");
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(str);
        while (matcher.find()) {
            System.out.println(matcher.group());
        }
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
a
b
:
123
+
234
-
345
*
456
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this one:

```
\D+?|\d+
```

+? - is lazy match for 1 repeater
and digits + from greedy match

see: [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/xfxgFY/1)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution without using regular expressions:

```java
private List<String> split(String input) {
  List<String> result = new ArrayList<>();
  StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
  for (char c : input.toCharArray()) {
    if (Character.isDigit(c)) {
      sb.append(c);
    } else {
      if (sb.length() > 0) {
        result.add(sb.toString());
        sb.setLength(0);
      }

      result.add(String.valueOf(c));
    }
  }
  if (sb.length() > 0) {
    result.add(sb.toString());
  }
  return result;
}
```